# AutoMapper and manually mapping nested complex types

Tags: c#, automapper

I have complex data, that is returned from my API as follows:

```
"id": 1002,
"user_id": "98fd8f37-383d-4fe7-9b88-18cc8a8cd9bf",
"organization_id": null,
"content": "A post with a hashtag!",
"created_at": "2018-05-25T21:35:31.5218467",
"modified_at": "2018-05-25T21:35:31.5218467",
"can_comment": true,
"can_share": true,
"post_tags": [
    {
        "post_id": 1002,
        "tag_id": 1,
        "tag": {
            "id": 1,
            "value": "hashtag",
            "post_tags": []
        }
    }
]
```

That corresponds to my `Post.cs` entity, and I created new model class to map it with, which looks like this:

```
public class PostModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public int? OrganizationId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public DateTime ModifiedAt { get; set; }

    public bool CanComment { get; set; } = true;

    public bool CanShare { get; set; } = true;

    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Where my `Tag.cs` and `TagModel.cs` classes lookk like this:

**Tag.cs:**

```
public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; } = new List<PostTag>();
}
```

**TagModel.cs:**

```
public int Id { get; set; }

[Required]
public string Value { get; set; }
```

So, basically, I have a mapping as

```
CreateMap<Post, PostModel>()
    .ReverseMap();
CreateMap<Tag, TagModel>()
    .ReverseMap();
```

but what I get from the API once I do the mapping is this:

```
"id": 1002,
"user_id": "98fd8f37-383d-4fe7-9b88-18cc8a8cd9bf",
"organization_id": null,
"content": "Finally a post with a hashtag!",
"created_at": "2018-05-25T21:35:31.5218467",
"modified_at": "2018-05-25T21:35:31.5218467",
"can_comment": true,
"can_share": true,
"tags": null
```

So, as you can see the `Tags` is not mapped. The reason is more likely that I have a many-to-many relationship between `Post` and `Tag`, and I originally get `PostTags` from the API. How can I tell AutoMapper to map the `tag` inside `post_tags` to the corresponding tag inside `PostModel`?

Comment: Use the `MapFrom` method in Automapper. See this blog post on how to utilize it. https://cpratt.co/using-automapper-creating-mappings/

Comment: @JamesFaix Can you give me a concrete example for my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AutoMapper maps the collection, not the objects in that collection, individually. So, first ignore the collection and then handle it manually.

```
// Map the Post and ignore the Tags
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Post, PostModel>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.Tags,
           opts => opts.Ignore());

// Map the Tags and ignore the post_tags
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Tag, TagModel>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.post_tags,
           opts => opts.Ignore());

// Map the Post Model
AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(post, postModel);

// Map the tags
for (int i = 0; i < post.post_tags.Count(); i++)
{
    AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(post.post_tags[i], postModel.Tags[i]);
}
```